Connecting to kafka from intellij
I have a kafka broker in k8s and doing a port forwarding using kubectl to 127.0.0.1:9092. Now I am able to connect to the kafka using the Big data tools plugin in Intellij without any issues. I am able to even start a consumer. Now when I run a python program to consume from kafka, it is unable to connect to the broker. Iget the below error

|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator:
0.0.0.0:54314: Connect to ipv4#0.0.0.0:54314 failed: Unknown error (after 0ms in state CONNECT)

But works fine when connecting with plugin. What could be the problem? I am having a windows machine.

You'll need to share your kafka configuration since 0.0.0.0 isn't a routable address and shouldn't be set as your kafka advertised.listeners
